# Catch a NSCAssert instruction in an objective-c module from a Swift project?

Tags: swift, objective-c

I am using a dependency written in Objective-C, which contains a singleton like this:

```
static TheLibrary *__sharedInstance = nil;

@implementation TheLibrary : NSObject

+ (instancetype)shared
{
    NSCAssert(__sharedInstance != nil, @"shared instance not initialized");
    return __sharedInstance;
}

@end
```

Problem is, when using `TheLibrary.shared()` from my Swift project, it happens sometimes that `sharedInstance` is nil and the app then gets killed with a `NSInternalInconsistencyException`.

I would like to know if there is some way to "catch" this error and handle it more smoothly instead of brutally killing the app?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+catch+objective-c+exception

Comment: Do you have access to the Objective-C code? There is no reason for the assert. There is a proper way to implement a singleton and that code isn't it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This is a third-party framework so I don't have access to it.

Comment: Then you should ask that question to vendor of that third-party framework.